# Error in Crystal Reports formula shows a big, red X

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have the following formula for a field in my Crystal Reports report shown in a `CrystalReportViewer`object :

```
ToText({myReport;1.NbEntries}, 0) + " entries"
```

Using this formula, the report generates correctly and everything's fine. However, I was asked to make that field optional. So I added a boolean parameter named `bEntries` and changed my formula this way :

```
If {?bEntries} Then
    ToText({myReport;1.NbEntries}, 0) + " entries"
Else
    ""
```

The formula editor does not show an error, however when I generate my report and `bEntries< is false, the control shows nothing but a large, red X inside. Reverting the formula back to its original value generates the report properly.

Is my formula wrong? What is causing the report to fail generating?

Comment: Why did you add the "1_1." in your second formula

Comment: I edited the names to protect the innocent, but it seems I forogot that one! Fixed.

Comment: I would try replacing "" with "(space)". Or maybe suppressing the field on bEntries. I have not hit the X yet.

Comment: Well I'll be damned... putting a space instead of the empty string fixed the problem. Just type it into an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the "" with "(space)".